# Using Firebase Auth for my react web app. Problems regarding account creation happening before sendEmailVerification and isEmailedVerified = true

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used firebase auth email/password sign in with the isEmailVerified property.  isEmailVerified set to true allows the user to get through to their logged in home page.  isEmailVerified set to false displays a screen telling the user to verify their email before they can get through.  Two problems here:

1. If a user creates an account with an email that is not theirs (I know email link sign up solves this, but looking for a solution via the email/password auth route), is there a way to discard of that account when the user doesn't verify their email within a certain amount of time?  Trying to avoid excess false/mistake accounts.
2. Lets say the user does use a correct email to sign up and they are through to their account after email verification, but they want to change their email at a later date (say via account settings using the updateEmail method, for example), then the user changing their email to an incorrect email would essentially make the user lose their account.  This is similar to problem #1, but worse, because in problem #1, some sort of solution that discards accounts with isEmailedVerified = false would discard an brand new account with no history, BUT with this problem, that same solution would discard a used account with history attached to it.  This is because the user would then have to login with the new incorrect email on their account, but isEmailVerified would be set to false, but they can never correct it since they don't have access to the new email.

These 2 problems happen because in firebase auth accounts are created before the sendEmailVerification is sent and isEmailVerified is set to true. Any solution?

I know email link sign up solves problem #1 since account creation and email verification happens together on initial sign up, but looking for a solution via the email/password route.  I don't think email link sign up solves problem #2.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function that checks your users list periodically and finds & removes users whose account has not been approved yet (after x days)

```js
// running periodically & using firebase admin SDK 

getAuth()
  .getUser(uid)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    console.log(userRecord)
    // if email is not verified & sign up date > x => delete user
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Here user Record will contain information about user's email verification.

Problem 2. You should allow another sign in method, i.e., phone, etc. so that if they lose the email, they can still verify their identify in another way. Otherwise your issue is a logical issue.
But if you want to keep it with just email, then you should not update their email right away, rather send verification and on the verification process you would also update their email. The logic needs to be handled in the backend.